# Return to the immediate previous cursor point after jumping around

Tags: emacs

Suppose such a situation:

I am working on a program of thousand line, when an idea occur to me and thus have to refer to the top of the file,
Strike Shift + < which jump to the top

Where a question come in, how could I return to the previous focus? I have that idea within 0.1 seconds  to refer to the top.

Solutions might be:
1. remember the current line number, M-g 1024 back then
2. take advantage of a register, C-x r s f (f for focus), after finished reference in 0.001 second, C-x r j f then back.

The above solutions are not pragmatic by which that sudden idea went vacuum.

How could return to the previous position in a straight-forward way?

Comment: Does `C-u C-SPC` do what you want? (It jumps to the location of the mark - and `M-<` sets the mark before jumping, so you get back to where you were.)

Comment: Yes Could you please transmit the comment to answer. and inform the function they invoke? my C-spec will switch the input method binded by desktop.   ivy-M-x  "jump mark" not help. @legoscia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C-u C-SPC` seems to do what you want.  It jumps to the location of the mark - and `M-<` sets the mark before jumping, so you get back to where you were before.  (`C-SPC` is bound to `set-mark-command`, but when invoked with a prefix argument it jumps to the mark instead of setting it.)

This would work when searching as well: `C-s` and `C-r` set the mark to the place where you started the search, so you can get back there quickly.

Comment: ty and surprising for the quick solution.  by the way I use C-@ where @ is intuitive  for address a mark.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the built-in `C-u C-SPC` I had exactly that use-case and wrote detour for it, which is package-installable: https://github.com/ska2342/detour

I just hit `C-.` to mark my current position, go somewhere else and then toggle between new and old position quickly with `C-,`.

Very tiny package, I prefer it over operating with the mark. Sometimes commands do funny things with the mark and then I lost my position.

Of course you can use registers, which detour uses under the hood, explicitly. `C-x r SPC` to store your point in a register (number or char) and `C-x r j` to jump to that register later.

Comment: Your default detour register seems odd to me.  It's not a character which could be typed easily, but it doesn't need to be a character at all.  Registers just need to be comparable with `eq` so it's usual in elisp to use a symbol. It's only interactively that they're expected to be characters.

Comment: I didn't really put too much thinking into the choice of the register. Way back almost 20 years ago I just wrote two functions and used register 8. Then I stuck to it. What would you suggest?

Comment: I'd probably have hard-coded `'detour` as the register, and not had the defcustom.  I doubt the current approach has ever caused anyone a single problem though, so it's not that important. I just wanted to point out that there was a better approach.

Comment: Hm, `(info "(emacs) Registers")` as well as docstring of `point-to-register` all mention characters as possible register names, limiting them explicitly to 255 registers. Allowing symbols would allow way more than 255. Can you give me some hints where to find docs on using symbols as registers? I tried it in *scratch*, it works with symbols. Register documentation is either misleading or stating the official contract.

Comment: You're quite right about the documentation.  Offhand I'm not sure whether my suggestion was ever a documented possibility or not.  Behind the scenes, though, `get-register` and `set-register` are just dealing with `register-alist` using `alist-get` which defaults to `eq` as an equality test, and that has been how it works in practice for as long as I've used them.